# angularjs draggable directive to display value inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

From the directive developer guide, i tried to twist one of the example about draggable directive and make it display it's coordinate too.

but my code change make the directive not draggable. The most significant change is that i added scope in the directive like below. anyone can offer help on this? full source can be found in link below. Thanks!

https://plnkr.co/edit/muegeHyOWC828IjI84Tt?p=preview

```
scope:{
    startX: '=', 
    startY: '=', 
    x: '=',
    y: '='
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working updated code of your's

```js
angular.module('dragModule', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.startX=0;
    $scope.startY=0;
    $scope.x=0;
    $scope.y=0;
  }])
  .directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
      scope:{
        startX: '=', 
        startY: '=', 
        x: '=',
        y: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {  
        element.css({
         position: 'relative',
         border: '1px solid red',
         backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
         cursor: 'pointer'
        });

        element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
          // Prevent default dragging of selected content
          event.preventDefault();
          scope.startX = event.pageX - scope.x;
          scope.startY = event.pageY - scope.y;
          $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
          scope.$apply();
        });
 
        function mousemove(event) {
          scope.y = event.pageY - scope.startY;
          scope.x = event.pageX - scope.startX;
          element.css({
            top: scope.y + 'px',
            left: scope.x + 'px'
          });
          scope.$apply();
        }

        function mouseup() {
          $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        }
      }
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="dragModule"> 
  <div ng-controller="myController"> 
    <span my-draggable start-x="startX" start-y="startY" x="x" y="y" id="drag">Drag Me({{x}},{{y}})</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Shubhamtri/w13sfaun/2/

Comment: Thanks. may i know why start-x="startX" etc is needed? what is the usage of scope: { startX: "=" }? isnt it used for binding the variable?

Comment: To access any parent scope data in two way binding between the controller and directive, we need to pass that to our directive explicitly.You can refer to this - https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't pass controler vars to directive:

```
<span my-draggable  
 startX="startX" startY="startY" 
 x="x" y="y" >
    Drag Me({{x}},{{y}})
</span>
```

<kbd>[**Demo Plunker 1**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pkJrxBawacwgQwQjWJQM?p=preview)</kbd>

---

But if you want to update also counters I would bind method instead:

```
  .directive('myDraggable', ['$document','$timeout', function($document,$timeout) {
    return {
      scope:{
        onChange: '&'
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

         scope.x=0;
         scope.y=0;
         scope.startX=0;
         scope.startY=0;

        element.css({
         position: 'relative',
         border: '1px solid red',
         backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
         cursor: 'pointer'
        });

        element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
          console.log('mousedown');
          // Prevent default dragging of selected content
          event.preventDefault();

          $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });



        function mousemove(event) {
            scope.y = event.pageY - scope.startY;
            scope.x = event.pageX - scope.startX;

            element.css({
              top: scope.y + 'px',
              left: scope.x + 'px'
            });  

           $timeout(function(){
            scope.onChange({data:{x:scope.x, y:scope.y}});
           });
        }

        function mouseup() {
          console.log('mouseup');
          $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        }
      }
    };
  }])
```

*Controller*

```
 $scope.onChange = function(data){
   $scope.x=data.x;
   $scope.y=data.y;
 }
```

*HTML*

```
  <span my-draggable  on-change="onChange(data)" >Drag Me({{x}},{{y}})</span>
```

<kbd>[**Demo Plunker 2**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Rap2euibQFWcy48j2nG?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Demo Plunker 1 missed the scope.$apply() as i compared with Shubham Tripathi answer. Plunker 2 works very well thanks. but i dont understand why i need to pass variable to directive and the binding cannot do the same job. any idea? thanks alot.

Comment: @CodeforFun the description is : it makes code simple and readable. with one callback we do all job and we don't need bind 4 items that will effect on performance. With demo 2 you can easily control update frequency, for  example: we can update x and y every 100 ms and not 1 ms.

Comment: @CodeforFun also $timeout makes the same as $apply - triggers digest cycle. However scope.$apply() can throw Exception if digest cycle already triggered